# Why not $(element).ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

The following code works

```
$("#someid").ready(function(){});
```

How good it is to use this? What happens in the background?

Comment: In which scenario would you like to use this?

Comment: is it tested inside `doc ready`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works only because it ignores the div ID, and defaults to the document.

`.ready()` is used to tell you when the DOM is finished loading, i.e. when **all** elements on the page have loaded.

If you would want to execute a function when an element is finished loading, you should use:

```
$("#someid").load(function() {
  // Do something here
});
```

That can only be used with...

> any element associated with a URL: images,
>   scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

Otherwise, `("#someid").ready` will work but only when the whole document is finished loading.

See http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: @WesleyMurch http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: I got it! But load doesn't work on div. Any other alternatives?

Comment: @Scorpion "This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object." No mention of `<div>` elements there.

Comment: I think adding a small background image to the div might be the trick to get it to work; If for example the 1px by 1px background image has loaded, then the DIV/element exists, and it just loaded.

Comment: As above - when used on a div element this is for loading content, not trapping a load event.

Comment: I think adding a background image to the div might be a plausible workaround

Answer (score 0):

Manual [says this](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> The `.ready()` method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document, so the selector can be omitted.

If we have a look at the [method's source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/ready.js#L10) we find this:

```
jQuery.fn.ready = function( fn ) {
    // Add the callback
    jQuery.ready.promise().done( fn );

    return this;
};
```

There's no code to handle the jQuery chain or the selector, what suggests that they're simply ignored.

And a [simple test](http://jsbin.com/UPIVuMU/1/) shows that the selector is simply ignored:

```
$("selector does not match anything").ready(function(){
    console.log("Event is triggered anyway");
});
```